# Strange problem with simple multithreading program in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am just starting play with multithreading programming. I would like to my program show alternately character '-' and '+' but it doesn't. My task is to use `synchronized` keyword. As far I have:

```
class FunnyStringGenerator{

    private char c;

    public FunnyStringGenerator(){
        c = '-';
    }

    public synchronized char next(){

        if(c == '-'){
            c = '+';
        }
        else{
            c = '-';
        }

        return c;
    }
}

class ThreadToGenerateStr implements Runnable{

    FunnyStringGenerator gen;

    public ThreadToGenerateStr(FunnyStringGenerator fsg){
        gen = fsg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            System.out.print(gen.next());
        }
    }


}

public class Main{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FunnyStringGenerator FSG = new FunnyStringGenerator();

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            exec.execute(new ThreadToGenerateStr(FSG));
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I also testing `Thread.sleep` in run method instead `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `synchronized` block in `FunnyStringGenerator.next()` is working fine.  It will return `'+'` and `'-'` alternately.

However you have a race condition in `ThreadToGenerateStr.run()`:

```
System.out.print(gen.next());
```

This is equivalent to:

```
char c = gen.next(); // Synchronized
System.out.print(c); // Not synchronized
```

The problem occurs when:

- Thread 1 calls gen.next(), getting a result of '-'
- Thread 2 calls gen.next(), getting a result of '+'
- Thread 2 calls System.out.print(), writing '+'
- Thread 1 calls System.out.print(), writing '-'

The result is that the '+' and '-' are written in the opposite order.

There are various possible workarounds, e.g.:

- Call both gen.next() and System.out.print() in a single `synchronized` block (as in dogbane's answer)
- Make gen.next() write the character to the stream instead of returning it
- Make gen.next() append the character to a shared [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and have a dedicated I/O thread taking characters from this queue and printing them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of synchronizing the method, do this:

```
        synchronized (gen) {
            System.out.print(gen.next());
        }
```

You need to wrap the entire print statement in a synchronized block so that another thread cannot change the value of `c` before you print it.

Think of it as two statements:

```
char n = gen.next();
System.out.print(n);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use two threads for printing each character and use this concept of wait and notify.